# Prediction using InceptionV3 in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, prediction

I have trained InceptionV3 model in tensor flow on my own dataset. I have the checkpoint file and the graph (.meta) from training. I am using these files to classify the label of a new image. Till now I have the following:

**inception_v3 code from TFslim**

```html
def inception_v3(inputs,
                 dropout_keep_prob=0.8,
                 num_classes=1000,
                 is_training=True,
                 restore_logits=True,
                 scope=''):
  """Latest Inception from http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567.
    "Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision"
    Christian Szegedy, Vincent Vanhoucke, Sergey Ioffe, Jonathon Shlens,
    Zbigniew Wojna
  Args:
    inputs: a tensor of size [batch_size, height, width, channels].
    dropout_keep_prob: dropout keep_prob.
    num_classes: number of predicted classes.
    is_training: whether is training or not.
    restore_logits: whether or not the logits layers should be restored.
      Useful for fine-tuning a model with different num_classes.
    scope: Optional scope for name_scope.
  Returns:
    a list containing 'logits', 'aux_logits' Tensors.
  """
  # end_points will collect relevant activations for external use, for example
  # summaries or losses.
  end_points = {}
  with tf.name_scope(scope, 'inception_v3', [inputs]):
    with scopes.arg_scope([ops.conv2d, ops.fc, ops.batch_norm, ops.dropout],
                          is_training=is_training):
      with scopes.arg_scope([ops.conv2d, ops.max_pool, ops.avg_pool],
                            stride=1, padding='VALID'):
        # 299 x 299 x 3
        end_points['conv0'] = ops.conv2d(inputs, 32, [3, 3], stride=2,
                                         scope='conv0')
        # 149 x 149 x 32
        end_points['conv1'] = ops.conv2d(end_points['conv0'], 32, [3, 3],
                                         scope='conv1')
        # 147 x 147 x 32
        end_points['conv2'] = ops.conv2d(end_points['conv1'], 64, [3, 3],
                                         padding='SAME', scope='conv2')
        # 147 x 147 x 64
        end_points['pool1'] = ops.max_pool(end_points['conv2'], [3, 3],
                                           stride=2, scope='pool1')
        # 73 x 73 x 64
        end_points['conv3'] = ops.conv2d(end_points['pool1'], 80, [1, 1],
                                         scope='conv3')
        # 73 x 73 x 80.
        end_points['conv4'] = ops.conv2d(end_points['conv3'], 192, [3, 3],
                                         scope='conv4')
        # 71 x 71 x 192.
        end_points['pool2'] = ops.max_pool(end_points['conv4'], [3, 3],
                                           stride=2, scope='pool2')
        # 35 x 35 x 192.
        net = end_points['pool2']
      # Inception blocks
      with scopes.arg_scope([ops.conv2d, ops.max_pool, ops.avg_pool],
                            stride=1, padding='SAME'):
        # mixed: 35 x 35 x 256.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_35x35x256a'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch5x5'):
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(net, 48, [1, 1])
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(branch5x5, 64, [5, 5])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 32, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_35x35x256a'] = net
        # mixed_1: 35 x 35 x 288.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_35x35x288a'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch5x5'):
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(net, 48, [1, 1])
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(branch5x5, 64, [5, 5])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 64, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_35x35x288a'] = net
        # mixed_2: 35 x 35 x 288.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_35x35x288b'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch5x5'):
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(net, 48, [1, 1])
            branch5x5 = ops.conv2d(branch5x5, 64, [5, 5])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 64, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch5x5, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_35x35x288b'] = net
        # mixed_3: 17 x 17 x 768.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x768a'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3'):
            branch3x3 = ops.conv2d(net, 384, [3, 3], stride=2, padding='VALID')
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 64, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 96, [3, 3],
                                      stride=2, padding='VALID')
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.max_pool(net, [3, 3], stride=2, padding='VALID')
          net = tf.concat([branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x768a'] = net
        # mixed4: 17 x 17 x 768.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x768b'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7'):
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(net, 128, [1, 1])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 128, [1, 7])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 192, [7, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7dbl'):
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 128, [1, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 128, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 128, [1, 7])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 128, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [1, 7])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x768b'] = net
        # mixed_5: 17 x 17 x 768.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x768c'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7'):
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(net, 160, [1, 1])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 160, [1, 7])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 192, [7, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7dbl'):
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 160, [1, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [1, 7])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [1, 7])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x768c'] = net
        # mixed_6: 17 x 17 x 768.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x768d'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7'):
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(net, 160, [1, 1])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 160, [1, 7])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 192, [7, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7dbl'):
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 160, [1, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [1, 7])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 160, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [1, 7])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x768d'] = net
        # mixed_7: 17 x 17 x 768.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x768e'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7'):
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 192, [1, 7])
            branch7x7 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7, 192, [7, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7dbl'):
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [1, 7])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [7, 1])
            branch7x7dbl = ops.conv2d(branch7x7dbl, 192, [1, 7])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch7x7, branch7x7dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x768e'] = net
        # Auxiliary Head logits
        aux_logits = tf.identity(end_points['mixed_17x17x768e'])
        with tf.variable_scope('aux_logits'):
          aux_logits = ops.avg_pool(aux_logits, [5, 5], stride=3,
                                    padding='VALID')
          aux_logits = ops.conv2d(aux_logits, 128, [1, 1], scope='proj')
          # Shape of feature map before the final layer.
          shape = aux_logits.get_shape()
          aux_logits = ops.conv2d(aux_logits, 768, shape[1:3], stddev=0.01,
                                  padding='VALID')
          aux_logits = ops.flatten(aux_logits)
          aux_logits = ops.fc(aux_logits, num_classes, activation=None,
                              stddev=0.001, restore=restore_logits)
          end_points['aux_logits'] = aux_logits
        # mixed_8: 8 x 8 x 1280.
        # Note that the scope below is not changed to not void previous
        # checkpoints.
        # (TODO) Fix the scope when appropriate.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_17x17x1280a'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3'):
            branch3x3 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
            branch3x3 = ops.conv2d(branch3x3, 320, [3, 3], stride=2,
                                   padding='VALID')
          with tf.variable_scope('branch7x7x3'):
            branch7x7x3 = ops.conv2d(net, 192, [1, 1])
            branch7x7x3 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7x3, 192, [1, 7])
            branch7x7x3 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7x3, 192, [7, 1])
            branch7x7x3 = ops.conv2d(branch7x7x3, 192, [3, 3],
                                     stride=2, padding='VALID')
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.max_pool(net, [3, 3], stride=2, padding='VALID')
          net = tf.concat([branch3x3, branch7x7x3, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_17x17x1280a'] = net
        # mixed_9: 8 x 8 x 2048.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_8x8x2048a'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 320, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3'):
            branch3x3 = ops.conv2d(net, 384, [1, 1])
            branch3x3 = tf.concat([ops.conv2d(branch3x3, 384, [1, 3]),
                                   ops.conv2d(branch3x3, 384, [3, 1])], 3)
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 448, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = tf.concat([ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [1, 3]),
                                      ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [3, 1])], 3)
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_8x8x2048a'] = net
        # mixed_10: 8 x 8 x 2048.
        with tf.variable_scope('mixed_8x8x2048b'):
          with tf.variable_scope('branch1x1'):
            branch1x1 = ops.conv2d(net, 320, [1, 1])
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3'):
            branch3x3 = ops.conv2d(net, 384, [1, 1])
            branch3x3 = tf.concat([ops.conv2d(branch3x3, 384, [1, 3]),
                                   ops.conv2d(branch3x3, 384, [3, 1])], 3)
          with tf.variable_scope('branch3x3dbl'):
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(net, 448, [1, 1])
            branch3x3dbl = ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [3, 3])
            branch3x3dbl = tf.concat([ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [1, 3]),
                                      ops.conv2d(branch3x3dbl, 384, [3, 1])], 3)
          with tf.variable_scope('branch_pool'):
            branch_pool = ops.avg_pool(net, [3, 3])
            branch_pool = ops.conv2d(branch_pool, 192, [1, 1])
          net = tf.concat([branch1x1, branch3x3, branch3x3dbl, branch_pool], 3)
          end_points['mixed_8x8x2048b'] = net
        # Final pooling and prediction
        with tf.variable_scope('logits'):
          shape = net.get_shape()
          net = ops.avg_pool(net, shape[1:3], padding='VALID', scope='pool')
          # 1 x 1 x 2048
          net = ops.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, scope='dropout')
          net = ops.flatten(net, scope='flatten')
          # 2048
          logits = ops.fc(net, num_classes, activation=None, scope='logits',
                          restore=restore_logits)
          # 1000
          end_points['logits'] = logits
          end_points['predictions'] = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='predictions')
      return logits, end_points
```

**Prediction code**

```html
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('path/to/meta/graph')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
with tf.Session(config=config,graph=graph) as sess:
        print graph
        saver.restore(sess,'/path/to/chpk/')
        init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables())
        sess.run(init_op)
        print ('Restored checkpoint file and graph')
      tens=image_preprocessing(tf.read_file('/serving/13_left.jpeg'))
        with slim.arg_scope(inception_arg_scope()):
               logits = inception_v3(tf.expand_dims(tens,0),
                               num_classes=6,
                               is_training=False)
        prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
        sess.run(prob)
```

This gives the following error:

```html
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value mixed_17x17x768d/branch7x7dbl/Conv_3/weights_2
  [[Node: mixed_17x17x768d/branch7x7dbl/Conv_3/weights_2/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@mixed_17x17x768d/branch7x7dbl/Conv_3/weights_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](mixed_17x17x768d/branch7x7dbl/Conv_3/weights_2)]]
```

I am fairly new to Tensorflow so any help here is much appreciated. I am doing something wrong, but just cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT 1**

I restarted my session by reloading the graph and weights into the session. I froze the graph and saved it as frozen_graph.pb. Following is my code:

```html
def freeze_graph(model_folder):
    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    absolute_model_folder = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_folder + "/frozen_model.pb"

    # Before exporting our graph, we need to precise what is our output node
    # This is how TF decides what part of the Graph he has to keep and what part it can dump
    output_node_names = "tower_0/logits/predictions"

    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We import the meta graph and retrieve a Saver
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

    # We retrieve the protobuf graph definition
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We start a session and restore the graph weights
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)
        for op in  sess.graph.get_operations():
                print(op.name)
        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
           ,output_node_names.split(",")) # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes


        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_folder", type=str, help="Model folder to export")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    freeze_graph(args.model_folder)
```

I load the frozen graph into a new session. Following are my node names:

```html
prefix/batch_processing/batch_join/fifo_queue
prefix/batch_processing/batch_join/n
prefix/batch_processing/batch_join
prefix/batch_processing/Reshape/shape
prefix/batch_processing/Reshape
.
.
.
prefix/logits/logits/weights
prefix/logits/logits/weights/read
prefix/logits/logits/biases
prefix/logits/logits/biases/read
prefix/tower_0/logits/logits/xw_plus_b/MatMul
prefix/tower_0/logits/logits/xw_plus_b
prefix/tower_0/logits/predictions
```

I use the input node and final node (predictions) to classify a new image. Following is my code for this:

```html
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we can use again a convenient built-in function to import a graph_def into the 
    # current default Graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def,
            input_map=None,
            return_elements=None,
            name="prefix",
            op_dict=None,
            producer_op_list=None
        )
    return graph

#graph = load_graph('/serving/frozen_model.pb')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import scipy.misc
    # Let's allow the user to pass the filename as an argument
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--frozen_model_filename", default="/serving/frozen_model.pb", type=str, help="Frozen model file to import")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # We use our "load_graph" function
    graph = load_graph(args.frozen_model_filename)

    # We can verify that we can access the list of operations in the graph
    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name)
        # prefix/Placeholder/inputs_placeholder
        # ...
        # prefix/Accuracy/predictions

    # We access the input and output nodes 
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/batch_processing/batch_join/fifo_queue:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/tower_0/logits/predictions:0')
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile('/serving/13_left.jpeg', 'rb').read()
    # We launch a Session
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        # Note: we didn't initialize/restore anything, everything is stored in the graph_def
        y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={
            x: image_data}) # < 45

        print(y_out) # [[ False ]] Yay, it works!
```

I get the following error.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_3.py", line 183, in <module>
    x: image_data}) # < 45
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in _run
    subfeed_dtype = subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 138, in as_numpy_dtype
    return _TF_TO_NP[self._type_enum]
KeyError: 20
```

Not sure of what is going wrong now. I see my nodes are correct. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you running?

Comment: I'm running TF v1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to resolve this issue. We have to freeze the graph in order to produce a .pb file that lets us re-use the nodes for prediction. Following is my code to do this:

```html
def freeze_graph(model_folder):
    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    absolute_model_folder = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    output_graph = absolute_model_folder + "/frozen_model.pb"

    # Before exporting our graph, we need to precise what is our output node
    # This is how TF decides what part of the Graph he has to keep and what part it can dump
    # NOTE: this variable is plural, because you can have multiple output nodes
    output_node_names = "tower_0/logits/predictions"

    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We import the meta graph and retrieve a Saver
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

    # We retrieve the protobuf graph definition
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We start a session and restore the graph weights
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)
        for op in  sess.graph.get_operations():
                print(op.name)
        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
           ,output_node_names.split(",")) # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes


        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_folder", type=str, help="Model folder to export")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    freeze_graph(args.model_folder)
```

After this, we can load the graph. Following is my code for this:

```html
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we can use again a convenient built-in function to import a graph_def into the 
    # current default Graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def,
            input_map=None,
            return_elements=None,
            name="prefix",
            op_dict=None,
            producer_op_list=None
        )
    return graph
```

This will create your protocol buffer (frozen_graph.pb), which we can lo

```html
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Let's allow the user to pass the filename as an argument
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--frozen_model_filename", default="/serving/frozen_model.pb", type=str, help="Frozen model file to import")
    parser.add_argument("--image_name",type=str,help="Image to test")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Create test batch
    image_data = create_test_batch(args.image_name)
    # We use our "load_graph" function
    graph = load_graph(args.frozen_model_filename)

    # We can verify that we can access the list of operations in the graph
    #for op in graph.get_operations():
        #print(op.name)
        # prefix/Placeholder/inputs_placeholder
        # ...
        # prefix/Accuracy/predictions

    # We access the input and output nodes 
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/batch_processing/Reshape:0') # Input tensor
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/tower_0/logits/predictions:0') # Output tensor

    # We launch a Session
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        # Note: we didn't initialize/restore anything, everything is stored in the graph_def
        y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={
            x:image_data}) # < 45    
        print(y_out)
```

My input node (x) expects a batch of size 64 and size 299x299x3 so I hacked my way by duplicating my test image 64 times and creating an input batch. I do this in the following way:

```html
def create_test_batch(input_image):
        data = []
        img = cv2.imread(input_image) # Read the test image
        img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV) # Convert RGB image to YUV
        # equalize the histogram of the Y channel
        img_yuv[:,:,0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_yuv[:,:,0])
        # convert the YUV image back to RGB format
        img_output = cv2.cvtColor(img_yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
        img_resize = cv2.resize(img_output,(299,299)) # Resize the image acceptable by InceptionV3 model
        for i in range(0,64):
                data.append(img_resize) # Create a batch of 64 images 
                #data.append(np.resize((ndimage.imread('/serving/'+input_image)),(299,299,3)))
        print np.shape(data)
        return data
```

If there is a better way of solving the input batch problem, I will appreciate an answer.