# Converting SSD to frozen graph in tensorflow. Which output node names must be used?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-ssd

I trained SSD using [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/06/supercharge-your-computer-vision-models.html) as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md).  It produces a ckpt, meta and index file.  In order to run it on my images I tried to check the demo code.  It requires that the model be converted to frozen graph.  I tried to convert my model to a frozen inference graph as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463896/prediction-using-inceptionv3-in-tensorflow).  In that program I have to provide output node names.  I could not figure out the name of the node in the SSD model which must be used here.  Please help.  I tried 'num_detections:0',  'detection_boxes:0' etc.  Only to get error:

AssertionError: num_detections is not in graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a special tool to convert to frozen graphs in the Tensorflow Object Detection API --- just run the [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py) binary. Directions for using this tool are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can explore graph by self: [A Tool Developer's Guide to TensorFlow Model Files](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/) and find node names. I can give sample from my model: "prefix/digit1/Softmax:0" (it was "digit1" in my keras model)
Also as I remember you should provide list of these names to transform_graph utility ("--output" parameter).

Answer (score 0):

i am using this small python script to localize nodes based on its operations.
"PLaceholder" and "Identity" appear to be interesting to find Input and Output Nodes:

```
import tensorflow as tf

NODE_OPS = ['Placeholder','Identity']
MODEL_FILE = '/path/to/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

gf = tf.GraphDef()
gf.ParseFromString(open(MODEL_FILE,'rb').read())

print([n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in (NODE_OPS)])
```